# How to pass an object in a list to another controller index function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net-mvc. I have a userList which contains information of few user, after check with the username input by user same with the UserName inside the list, how do I pass the matched user to another controller by using the RedirectToAction method?

**LoginController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Authorise(Models.User x)
{
    List<User> userList = new List<User>();
    userList.Add(new User { UserName = "A", Password = "A", EmpName ="A", EmpID = "ABC123", EmpEmail = "test@gmail.com", EmpContact = "1300882525" });
    userList.Add(new User { UserName = "B", Password = "B", EmpName = "B", EmpID = "ABC123", EmpEmail = "test@gmail.com", EmpContact = "1300882525" });
    userList.Add(new User { UserName = "C", Password = "C", EmpName = "C", EmpID = "ABC123", EmpEmail = "test@gmail.com", EmpContact = "1300882525" });
    userList.Add(new User { UserName = "E", Password = "E", EmpName = "E", EmpID = "ABC123", EmpEmail = "test@gmail.com", EmpContact = "1300882525" });

    var username = x.UserName;
    var pass = x.Password;

    //String UserName = Request.Form["UserName"];
    //String Password = Request.Form["Password"];

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (!userList.Exists(y => y.UserName == username) && !userList.Exists(y => y.Password == pass))
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "Wrong username or password.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else if (userList.Exists( y => y.UserName == username) )
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
        }
    }

    return View("Index");
}

public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    Session.Abandon();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
}
```

**UserController.cs**
*How do I pass the object inside this controller*

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{            
    List<PurchaseHistory> List1 = new List<PurchaseHistory>();

    List1.Add(new PurchaseHistory { empName = "A", ItemName = "Speaker", DateTime = new DateTime(2018,12,25) });
    List1.Add(new PurchaseHistory { empName = "B", ItemName = "Speaker", DateTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 25) });
    List1.Add(new PurchaseHistory { empName = "C", ItemName = "Speaker", DateTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 25) });
    List1.Add(new PurchaseHistory { empName = "C", ItemName = "Laptop", DateTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 25) });
    List1.Add(new PurchaseHistory { empName = "E", ItemName = "Speaker", DateTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 25) });
    List1.Add(new PurchaseHistory { empName = "E", ItemName = "Speaker", DateTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 25) });

    if (List1.Exists( y => y.empName == x.EmpName))
    {
        x.ListPurchaseHistory = List1.FindAll(y => y.empName.Equals(x.EmpName));
    }

    return View(x);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `Models.User` into `TempData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass object as `RouteData`

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { data = "YourData" });
```

With target action

```
public ActionResult Action(string data) {
  //action
}
```

However keep in mind that it will make redirect which is effectively `Get request` and your passed data is stored in url. It is not best practise to pass complex object with get requests. If your object is large enough it could cause `HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long`.

Better solution would be to use `Session`, `TempData` or other data container.

For session that would be like

```
this.Session["User"] = user;
```

and retrieve it with

```
User user  = (User)this.Session["User"];
```

Base on use you might need to check that session for null value.

If you end up using other container, you cant use `ViewBag` because `Viewbag` holds its data only for that request for which he was set up. Since `RedirectToAction` will make new Http request, your `ViewBag` is no longer available.

Comment: Does `ViewBag` retain data after first redirect?

Comment: Sadly no, I have modified my answer. It was misleading.

Comment: The top session is storing an user object but not a whole list right?

Comment: I dont know what you mean with top session. However session will store whatever you want. if you pass only user object to session, it will contains only that.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. use TempData
2. use anonymous object and change the action signature:

   ```
   RedirectToAction("Index", new { user = your_user })

   // ...

   public ActionResult Index(User user)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Out of context, I would like to raise security warnings on your code.

#### About searching for the user

```
if (!userList.Exists(y => y.UserName == username) && 
    !userList.Exists(y => y.Password == pass))
{
    TempData["Message"] = "Wrong username or password.";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here you are validating that *there exists a specific username in the database* and that *there exists a specific password in the database*. This means that you may authenticate a user with someone else's password!

I suggest you first find the correct user and **then** compare the password.

```
var user = userList.SingleOrDefault(y => y.UserName == username);
if (user != null)
{
    if (user.Password != null && user.Password.Equals(pass))
    {
        // ok
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["Message"] = "Wrong username or password.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
else
{
    TempData["Message"] = "Wrong username or password.";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

#### About future password storage

Secondly, you are not hashing user passwords. This is a classic security issue.  See [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

#### About authentication

In general, authenticating users is done with peers-validated libraries that are known to have zero security flaws.